# Image Alignment

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, margins

So my latex document looks like this:

[image]

So as you can see, the picture is aligning vertically with the text, however I need it centered, in other words I need the image moved to the left more so the left and right spaces match. I tried to wrap this image with a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` but that functionally did nothing.

Any ideas on how I can get it centered better?

Answer (score 3):

If the image is wider than `\textwidth` then centering will do nothing, all excess width of the over-full box will go into the right margin.  It appears that you do not want to scale the image but rather let it stick into the margins. In that case you need to hide its width, for example this puts it in a 0-sized box and then centers the result.

```
{\centering\par
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics{...}}
\par}
```